# Adding external JAR to Maven project in NetBeans

Tags: maven, netbeans, jar, external

When I right click on my Maven project and choose the *Add dependency* option and I type my external jar's name in query, it is not found. How to add external jar to a Maven project?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can follow this tutorial:
http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html

Example:

Install the jar to your local maven repository:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=cxf-2.7.3.jar -DgroupId=org.apache.cxf -DartifactId=cxf-bundle -Dversion=2.7.3 -Dpackaging=jar
```

Edit the pom.xml file in your project to include the newly added dependency:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
<artifactId>cxf-bundle</artifactId>
<version>2.7.3</version>
</dependency>
```

This should work regardless of the IDE you are using.

Comment: Important : Put the groupId, artifactId and version values between double quotation marks otherwise you won't get your jar placed correctly in the .m2 directory structure.  E.g. :  `mvn install:install-file -Dfile="C:\Users\pierr\JavaAPI.jar" -DgroupId="com.moneris" -DartifactId="api" -Dversion="1.0.18" -Dpackaging=jar`.  Tested in Windows 10 with Maven 3.6.2.

Answer (score 114):

From the [NetBeans forum](http://forums.netbeans.org/topic22907.html):

1. Open the **Projects** tab.
2. Right-click on **Dependencies**.
3. Select **Add dependency**.
4. Set **groupId** to: `group.id` (can be anything)
5. Set **artifactId** to: `artifact.id` (can be anything)
6. Set **version** to: `1.0` (can be anything)
7. Click **Add** to continue.

Dependency is added to `pom.xml` and appears under the **Libraries** node of Maven project. Continue:

1. Expand **Dependencies**.
2. Right-click on library (e.g., **group.id**).
3. Select **Manually install artifact**.
4. Set **Artifact to install** with the Java Archive (.jar) file path.
5. Click **Install locally**.

Library is installed locally with dependency attributes (*coordinates*) entered in steps 4 - 6.

---

I found those instructions helpful when going through the NetBeans GUI. Basically when right clicking to add a dependency, the group id, version, and name must be populated with anything.  Then that "dependency" will be listed in the dependency drop down.  Right click on that newly created dependency and right click to install locally and navigate to the appropriate jar file.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this

Comment: This should really be the accepted answer, given the question.

Comment: "Dependency with given groupId and artifactId is already defined in project". I have this particular library (JUnit) listed under "Test Dependencies" automatically by NetBeans, but I need to move it to "Dependencies".

Comment: after I add the dependency I can't expand the dependencies thing.

Comment: I don't see manually install artifact option.  I'm using Netbeans 11

Answer (score 7):

In Netbeans, the approach to adding dependencies that are not in repository is reversed. First come up with maven coordinates in the Add Dependency dialog. Then right click on the new dependency node and trigger "Manually install Artifact" action.

Answer (score 5):

**This answer is for jars that are in the maven repo**

Let's say I want to add `log4j-1.2.17.jar` to my project, all I have to do is find it in [maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j/1.2.17)

[image]

**Step 2** is to copy that and place it inside the dependencies tag of your pom.xml` file:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
     ....
     ....
  <dependencies>
```

**Step 3** Build and clean your project. The jar file will be in your dependencies folder afterwards

[image]

Answer (score 0):

one trick is in the netbeans main menu select: profile->options->java->maven put in the global execution options the parameters example: -Dfile=C:\Users\anonym\Desktop\commons-pool-1.6.jar -DgroupId=commons-pool -DartifactId=commons-pool -Dversion=1.6 -Dpackaging=jar

where de parameter -Dfile is the location of the jar file
-Dfile=routeToJar

after that select your project. then rigth clic on the select project. and then select Run Maven->Goal. when the wizard appear type in as Goals install:install-file   .. and then clic OK buttom