# add a jar and its dependencies to maven project in netbeans

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I need to add a local jar to my maven project in netbeans. I have followed these instructions so far (like in [Adding external JAR to Maven project in NetBeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17693040/adding-external-jar-to-maven-project-in-netbeans)):

```
1) Click "Add dependency" 
2) Insert some groupId, artifactId and version
3) After the new node is added in the POM.xml I right-click on the dependency 
added and I "manually install artifact".
```

However, I am having a problem because this jar is not self-contained and relies on a lib folder to work properly... is there a way to manage its dependencies or add the lib folder to the new dependency I have just created?