# Accessing external JAR library in Java EE Webservice with JSF and EJB

Tags: java, jsf, ejb, cdi

I just started developing with `Java EE` and `JSF 2.x`. Till now I'm very proud of my small applications with `Connection` to databases and `ldap`.

Now I need to connect to our `Application API` via some `exteral jar` libraries(`C:\Program\A\lib1.jar`, `C:\Program\A\lib2.jar`) so that I can add / change things / settings via `JSF Webpages` over `Application API`.

I have no idea how to solve this.
Any idea or helpful explanation or tutorial how to do that? (I'm using `Wildfly 10.1`) and I'm **not** using `Maven`.

Putting the jar files as dependency leads to a `ClassNotFound exception`.
It would be very helpful to get an example on how to add and accesses `external jar` libraries.

Comment: put the libs as dependency to your war

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17693040/adding-external-jar-to-maven-project-in-netbeans

Comment: thanks, but I don't use `Maven` in my Project. Adding the jar as depency leads to a ClassNotFound exception.