# Add a project to a mavem netbeans project

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

I am trying to add babelnet api to my project I add the main jar to.m2/repository and the using the pom inside that jar I called all the jars that they need to run their project. The problem is that the babelnet has a config folder where they define the enums, when I try to run the program I get an error involving the enums.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/babelscape/util/POS
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.babelscape.util.POS
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
```

How can I add the config files (they are properties extension files) to my project so I can run without error. The babelnet api doesn't have the support for the maven project (can't add it to the pom). 
Thanks for the help

Comment: Solution in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55443764/add-a-project-to-a-mavem-netbeans-project/55457834#55457834

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly resolved this problem. To resolve this problem i used the response in this post [Adding external JAR to Maven project in NetBeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17693040/adding-external-jar-to-maven-project-in-netbeans) (the Paul answer) and basicly added 3 libraries one for the original jar (**babelnet-api-4.0.1.jar**) one for **the lcl-jlt-2.4.jar** and for babelscape-data-**commons-1.0.jar**. The i added the rest of the jar in the pom.

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>logkit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logkit</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>avalon-framework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>avalon-framework</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
            <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
            <version>7.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
            <artifactId>lucene-analyzers-common</artifactId>
            <version>7.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
            <artifactId>lucene-queryparser</artifactId>
            <version>7.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>23.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>animal-sniffer-annotations</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.j2objc</groupId>
                    <artifactId>j2objc-annotations</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.errorprone</groupId>
                    <artifactId>error_prone_annotations</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>edu.mit</groupId>
            <artifactId>jwi</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.icu</groupId>
            <artifactId>icu4j</artifactId>
            <version>56.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Now i can compile and run my code.