# Adding the Apache Common Math 3.6.1 project from Maven Repository to a Maven project in NetBeans 12.x

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, jar, apache-commons

**Summary**: I wanted to use the prime number functions in the Apache Common Math project to solve a prime number problem.  The Apache NetBeans IDE 12.2 complains “cannot find symbol” isPrime()  and the programs fails to compile.
What’s going on?

**Detailed info**:

Using Apache NetBeans IDE 12.2 running on Windows 10, I created a Maven Java app project.
Then I followed the instructions posted by Ojonugwa Jude Ochalifuon on Mar 24 '18  [Adding external JAR to Maven project in NetBeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17693040/adding-external-jar-to-maven-project-in-netbeans)

Specifically,

1. I copied the Maven dependency XML from the Apache Math 3.6.1

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-math3 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-math3</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

2. and pasted it into my project’s **pom.xml**
3. Next, in the NetBeans 12.2 IDE, I performed a **Clean and Build Project**.  The process downloaded all of the Apache Commons 3.6.1 files and compiled the project successfully.  In the Projects tab, under the Dependencies folder, I saw the **commons.math3-3.6.1.jar**. I navigated down to the **Primes.class**.
4. Next, I added the following import command to my .java file:

```
    import org.apache.commons.math3.primes.Primes;
```

The NetBean 12.2 IDE displayed a yellow squiggle under the import reporting “unused Import.”

5. Then I added the following code snippet:

```
    if (isPrime(candidate)) { … }
```

The NetBean 12.2 IDE displayed a red squiggle under the **isPrime()** method (which is defined in the Apache Math 3.6.1 package).

When I press Shift+F6 to run the file, I get the following compile-time error:

Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project ProjectEuler: Compilation failure
robcor/projecteuler/Problem0027.java:[20,16] **error: cannot find symbol**

What’s going on?

Thanks in advance for your help. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe,

if (Primes.isPrime(candidate)) { … }

solves your problem.

Comment: Yes it does.  Thanks.