# How to add javafx to java 15.01 sdk using netbeans

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans-platform

New to Java here. I have a java project on netbeans using maven. I am trying to add javafx to my project.

I added the following to my pom.xml file :

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx</artifactId>
            <version>15</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
```

But when i try and build my project in netbeans I get this error (tsInfluence is the class which contains the main method that is trying to call jfx):

```
Error: LinkageError occurred while loading main class com.ts.tsInfluence.tsInfluence
    java.lang.ClassFormatError: Invalid superclass index 0 in class file com/ts/tsInfluence/tsInfluence
Command execution failed.
```

Comment: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/ ..

Answer (score 0):

Go to project properties -> Libraries -> Add a new classpath (Library) -> Give name etc -> than add the path to the scr zip of javafx

**Edit:**
Doesnt a window like this appear to you? right mouse button on project name
[image]

**Edit 2:**
Oh right... in maven you need to follow this
http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html

A similiar question was answered here... you should follow what they say and just replace the file path for yours

[Question close to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17693040/adding-external-jar-to-maven-project-in-netbeans)

Comment: When I go to project properties there is no libraries option, any idea why? @MrSano43

Comment: the libraries tab doesnt show for me, possibly since my project is using maven ?

Comment: This answer is misleading because the OP has a Maven project.

Comment: Yeah sorry did not paid enough attention to that , made  a new edit with a link to another answered question that has the tutorial on how to do it.

Comment: @kleopatra i did o.O

Comment: JavaFX should be on the Modulepath, not the Classpath.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to build applications with JavaFX is to use a build of OpenJDK that includes the JavaFX modules.  BellSoft and Azul both have variants of OpenJDK that bundle the JavaFX modules. Bellsoft's Liberica JDK calls this the "Full JDK", Zulu just calls it the "JDK FX" package. Beware that Bellsoft's version may not include the full media support - read the notes.

https://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu-community/?package=jdk-fx

Otherwise, follow the instructions at https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#maven

Comment: Not sure why this got a downvote. It's not wrong.

Answer (score -2):

Your setup does not work because "javafx" is not a valid artifact id. You have to provide (possibly more than one) dependencies like this.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
    <version>15.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

For more details read the documentation: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#maven